# Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists. Drupal 8

Tags: php, cms, drupal

Estou tentando realizar o envio do e-mail de recuperação de senha no Drupal 8, porém, quando insiro o e-mail e envio, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

"Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
"

- Qual uma forma de eu ter mais detalhes sobre esse erro? Sou novo no drupal e não conheço muito sobre o debug nele, gostaria de saber se existe alguma for de ver um error_log ou um detalhe mais técnico sobre o problema.

Comment: Já checou o log de erros do PHP?

Comment: Estou procurando dentro da hierarquia de pastar do drupal algum error_log e não acho

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ver o log de erros no menu administrativo (reports -> Recent log messages).

[image: drupal errors log]

Se você usar o drush (versão 9), no console digite, dentro da pasta de seu projeto, o comando "drush ws".